# File shows zero kb after upload in python flask

Tags: python, file-upload, flask

I am building rest api in python.
I am trying to upload a video file in python and get thumbnail of it.
But when the file is uploaded the file shows a size of zero kb.

Below is the snapshot of my code:

```
import json

from flask import Flask, make_response, request, abort, logging, Response
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
#from flask.ext.uploads import delete, init, save, Upload

app = Flask("main")

app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['mp4','jpg'])
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads/'


@app.route('/import', methods=['POST'])
def import_objects():
    file = request.files['file']
    # logging.debug('uploading file ' + file.filename)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        # extract content
        content = file.read()
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        print(filename)
        print(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        #save(request.files['file'])
        #print content
        print('ffmpeg -i ./'+os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)+' -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -f image2 ' + os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],'thumb1.jpg'))
        os.system('ffmpeg -i ./'+os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)+' -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -f image2 ' + os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],'thumb1.jpg'))

        jsonResponse = json.dumps({'file_content': content})
        response = Response(jsonResponse, mimetype='application/json')
        return "sucess"
    else:
        abort(make_response("File extension not acceptable", 400))


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']


app.run("0.0.0.0", 8080, True)
```

hear Is the my code snip of html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://0.0.0.0:8080/import" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: after file upload when i check it shows it size as 0 kb @abarisone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added file.close() and removed content=file.read() and it worked . Thankx @Brain KH

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your `content = file.read()` is messing it up. Remove that line and it should work. You don't need to read the file before saving it. Just save it.

Comment: also file was left to close

Answer (score 1):

I know this is rather old question but anybody bumps into a similar situation, apart from deleting the `.read()` line, you can just do this:

```
file.seek(0)
```